# Screen flickering on Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 - 4K resolution

Tags: 14.04, dell, 4k-monitor

I have a Dell Inspiron 7548 with a 4k resolution screen.
When I first installed Ubuntu on this machine I had a screen flickering issue, but I solved it passing the option **i915.enable_IPS=0** to the kernel upon boot (source: [Askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/584212/how-to-resolve-screen-flickering-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts-and-dell-inspiron-15-7000-s) and [bugs.freedesktop](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=83497)).

But now, after an official kernel update (3.19.0.30) this tip doesn't work anymore. No problem if I go back to 3.19.0.28.

Any suggestions?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I think I've solved the issue by myself, I'm posting what I've done hoping that this will help someone else.

The solution is quite simple: the new kernel works out-of-the-box, this means that the instruction **i915.enable_IPS=0** is not needed anymore.

So, to solve the problem, open a terminal and type:
`gedit /etc/default/grub` then search for the "`i915.enable_IPS=0`" and remove it.
Save, close and rebuild grub configuration with: `sudo grub-mkconfig`

Reboot and voilà!

Comment: it worked just for few minutes, situation not solved :(

Comment: Did you manage solving this in the meantime?