# Screen flickering with Ubuntu 15 on MSI PE 60 2QE

Tags: drivers, display, nomodeset, msi, kms

My new MSI PE60 2QE laptop mounts an Intel Integrated Graphics Chipset 5600 connected to a Samsung 156HL01-102 display.

The display works perfectly when I boot with the "nomodeset" parameter in the kernel command line -- but using the framebuffer driver, which doesn't allow multiple monitors.

With KMS enabled (by removing the "nomodeset" parameter), X starts correctly with the intel drivers and I can use multiple monitors, but the laptop's panel shows an irregular flicker, ranging from occasional flickering horizontal black lines (which are really annoying) to a constant flashing & flickering making the display all but unusable.

An external monitor connected to the DP port works well. I've not tried the HDMI yet.

Things I have tried (among many others I've discovered were irrelevant):
* Creating a new (1.3) EDID matching the displays characteristics as recommended in https://www.osadl.org/Single-View.111+M5ec938a7b3b.0.html
* Setting different video modes using xrandr
* Booting with Kernel 3.19.0.25 with i915.enable_IPS=0 as suggested here: [Screen flickering on Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 - 4K resolution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/680703/screen-flickering-on-ubuntu-gnome-14-04-4k-resolution)
* Booting with i915.powersave=0
* Booting with acpi_osi=Linux

How can I get the intel drivers to work without this flickering?

About the hardware:

```
$ lspci|grep -E "VGA|3D"
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 0a)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 139b (rev a2)
```

About the display:

```
$ sudo get-edid -q|edid-decode 
Intel(R) HSW Mobile/Desktop Graphics Chipset Accelerated VGA BIOSExtracted contents:
header:          00 ff ff ff ff ff ff 00
serial number:   4c 83 4c 32 00 00 00 00 00 17
version:         01 04
basic params:    95 22 13 78 0a
chroma info:     ce 85 9e 5b 4c 94 26 17 50 54
established:     00 00 00
standard:        01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01
descriptor 1:    dc 37 80 a0 70 38 40 40 30 20 25 00 58 c2 10 00 00 19
descriptor 2:    00 00 00 0f 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 1e 82 10 52 00
descriptor 3:    00 00 00 fe 00 53 41 4d 53 55 4e 47 0a 20 20 20 20 20
descriptor 4:    00 00 00 fe 00 31 35 36 48 4c 30 31 2d 31 30 32 0a 20
extensions:      00
checksum:        d1

Manufacturer: SDC Model 324c Serial Number 0
Made week 0 of 2013
EDID version: 1.4
Digital display
6 bits per primary color channel
DisplayPort interface
Maximum image size: 34 cm x 19 cm
Gamma: 2.20
Supported color formats: RGB 4:4:4, YCrCb 4:2:2
First detailed timing is preferred timing
Established timings supported:
Standard timings supported:
Detailed mode: Clock 143.000 MHz, 344 mm x 194 mm
               1920 1968 2000 2080 hborder 0
               1080 1082 1087 1144 vborder 0
               -hsync -vsync
Manufacturer-specified data, tag 15
ASCII string: SAMSUNG
     ASCII string: 156HL01-102
 Checksum: 0xd1
EDID block does NOT conform to EDID 1.3!
    Missing name descriptor
    Missing monitor ranges
```

xrandr output:

$ xrandr --verbose

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (0x6a) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
    Identifier: 0x63
    Timestamp:  13894
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
    Brightness: 1.0
    Clones:    
    CRTC:       1
    CRTCs:      1 0 2
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff004c834c3200000000
        00170104952213780ace859e5b4c9426
        17505400000001010101010101010101
        010101010101dc3780a0703840403020
        250058c2100000190000000f00000000
        00000000001e82105200000000fe0053
        414d53554e470a2020202020000000fe
        00313536484c30312d3130320a2000d1
    BACKLIGHT: 4882 
        range: (0, 4882)
    Backlight: 4882 
        range: (0, 4882)
    scaling mode: Full aspect 
        supported: None, Full, Center, Full aspect
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
  1920x1080 (0x6a)  143.0MHz -HSync -VSync *current +preferred
        h: width  1920 start 1968 end 2000 total 2080 skew    0 clock   68.8KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1082 end 1087 total 1144           clock   60.1Hz
  1920x1080 (0x12c)  138.5MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1920 start 1968 end 2000 total 2080 skew    0 clock   66.6KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1111           clock   59.9Hz
  1680x1050 (0x12d)  146.2MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1680 start 1784 end 1960 total 2240 skew    0 clock   65.3KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1089           clock   60.0Hz
  1680x1050 (0x12e)  119.0MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1680 start 1728 end 1760 total 1840 skew    0 clock   64.7KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1080           clock   59.9Hz
  1600x1024 (0x12f)  103.1MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1600 start 1600 end 1656 total 1664 skew    0 clock   62.0KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1024 end 1029 total 1030           clock   60.2Hz
  1400x1050 (0x130)  122.0MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1400 start 1488 end 1640 total 1880 skew    0 clock   64.9KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1052 end 1064 total 1082           clock   60.0Hz
  1280x1024 (0x131)  108.0MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock   64.0KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock   60.0Hz
  1440x900 (0x132)  106.5MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1440 start 1520 end 1672 total 1904 skew    0 clock   55.9KHz
        v: height  900 start  903 end  909 total  934           clock   59.9Hz
  1280x960 (0x133)  108.0MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1376 end 1488 total 1800 skew    0 clock   60.0KHz
        v: height  960 start  961 end  964 total 1000           clock   60.0Hz
  1360x768 (0x134)   84.8MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1360 start 1432 end 1568 total 1776 skew    0 clock   47.7KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  781 total  798           clock   59.8Hz
  1360x768 (0x135)   72.0MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1360 start 1408 end 1440 total 1520 skew    0 clock   47.4KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  781 total  790           clock   60.0Hz
  1152x864 (0x136)   81.6MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1152 start 1216 end 1336 total 1520 skew    0 clock   53.7KHz
        v: height  864 start  865 end  868 total  895           clock   60.0Hz
  1024x768 (0x137)   65.0MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock   48.4KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock   60.0Hz
  800x600 (0x138)   40.0MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock   37.9KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock   60.3Hz
  800x600 (0x139)   36.0MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  824 end  896 total 1024 skew    0 clock   35.2KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  603 total  625           clock   56.2Hz
  640x480 (0x13a)   25.2MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock   31.5KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock   59.9Hz
DP1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (0x6b) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 477mm x 268mm
    Identifier: 0x64
    Timestamp:  13894
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
    Brightness: 1.0
    Clones:     HDMI1
    CRTC:       0
    CRTCs:      1 0 2
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff0010ac60404c4e4141
        2d1401030e301b78ea9535a159579f27
        0e5054a54b00714f8180d1c001010101
        010101010101023a801871382d40582c
        4500dd0c1100001e000000ff00343257
        313930423941414e4c0a000000fc0044
        454c4c205032323131480a20000000fd
        00384c1e5311000a202020202020005b
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
  1920x1080 (0x6b)  148.5MHz +HSync +VSync *current +preferred
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock   67.5KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock   60.0Hz
  1280x1024 (0x13b)  135.0MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1296 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock   80.0KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock   75.0Hz
  1280x1024 (0x131)  108.0MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock   64.0KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock   60.0Hz
  1152x864 (0x13c)  108.0MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1152 start 1216 end 1344 total 1600 skew    0 clock   67.5KHz
        v: height  864 start  865 end  868 total  900           clock   75.0Hz
  1024x768 (0x13d)   78.8MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1040 end 1136 total 1312 skew    0 clock   60.1KHz
        v: height  768 start  769 end  772 total  800           clock   75.1Hz
  1024x768 (0x137)   65.0MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock   48.4KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock   60.0Hz
  800x600 (0x13e)   49.5MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  816 end  896 total 1056 skew    0 clock   46.9KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  604 total  625           clock   75.0Hz
  800x600 (0x138)   40.0MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock   37.9KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock   60.3Hz
  640x480 (0x13f)   31.5MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  720 total  840 skew    0 clock   37.5KHz
        v: height  480 start  481 end  484 total  500           clock   75.0Hz
  640x480 (0x140)   25.2MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock   31.5KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock   60.0Hz
  720x400 (0x141)   28.3MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   720 start  738 end  846 total  900 skew    0 clock   31.5KHz
        v: height  400 start  412 end  414 total  449           clock   70.1Hz
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x65
    Timestamp:  13894
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:     DP1
    CRTCs:      1 0 2
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    aspect ratio: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, 4:3, 16:9
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x66
    Timestamp:  13894
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:    
    CRTCs:      1 0 2
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    aspect ratio: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, 4:3, 16:9
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x67
    Timestamp:  13894
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:    
    CRTCs:      1 0 2
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x68
    Timestamp:  13894
    Subpixel:   no subpixels
    Clones:    
    CRTCs:      3
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter:
```

Comment: After a lot of tinkering, I managed to get NVIDIA GPU to work together with the Intel card (via xrandr --setprovideroutputsource). It works awsomely (GLXgears at 12500 FPS at default size, or 2900 FPS full screen).... But the flickering is still there :-(

Comment: Some recent upgrade fixed the issue -- I'm now at Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off "Unredirect fullscreen windows" in compizconfig or use the terminal:

```
gconftool-2 --set /apps/compizconfig-1/profiles/Default/plugins/composite/screen0/options/unredirect_fullscreen_windows --type bool 0
```

Comment: Didn't help. Clarification, in case it matters: the flickering lines appear even before logging in (I believe compiz has not kicked in yet at that point, right?).

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem install the latest current stable **short-lived branch  NVIDIA drivers 355**.

But first undo all the changes you have made to set the system back to standard configuration.

Remove all parameters  - uninstall every NVIDIA related software you have had installed before.

Boot into the Ubuntu system and when the login screen appears press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.

Enter your user name and password and then execute:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

Note:

If you had bumblebee installed remove the packages as well (it will be replaced by nvidia-prime).

In this case the commands would be:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia* bumblebee  
sudo reboot
```

Now install the new drivers and NVIDIA Optimus support.

When the login screen appears press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>.

Enter your user name and password and then execute:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-355 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

In case you have to adjust which card to use in BIOS select **NVIDIA** or  **switchable graphics mode**.

Open **NVIDIA X Server Settings** -> **Prime Profiles** to switch between the intel and NVIDIA GPUs.

Comment: Is this the driver you're referring to? (I can't find any reference to "short-lived branch"): http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/90393/en-us

Comment: Sorry, ignore the question. Had not read through to your reference to the graphics-drivers ppa. I'll try your recipe during this weekend. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Followed your steps and got both modes to work: low-consumption with the intel drivers worked right away, while high-performance with the modesetting + NVIDIA drivers required a configuring a display-setup-script in lightdm running xrandr --setprovideroutputsource modesetting NVIDIA-0 && xrandr --auto.

Unfortunately the flickering is still there in both modes.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problems with flickering on Ubuntu. In my case helped disabling "Unknown display" in Settings -> Displays. Maybe it'll work also in your case.

Comment: I don't have any "unknown display" in the Display Settings :--( Thanks anyway for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

Using 17.04 alpha

This stopped the flashing for me; nano to /etc/modprobe.d/i915.conf and add the following (usually the file does not already exist) and reboot:

*# added by DW 3.3.2017 attempt to stop i915 flashing

options i915 enable_rc6=7 enable_psr=2 enable_fbc=1 lvds_downclock=1 semaphores=1*